# Migration script fires 'The data definition language (DDL) command cannot be executed at the Subscriber'

Tags: sql-server-2008, ddl, scripting

Yesterday I had run a migration script, produced by Visual Studio 2008 *schema compare* option, on a SQL Server 2008 database. It had run correctly.

But today, when I executed the same script, it threw a wierd exception in SQL Server:

```
Altering dbo.YourTableHere...

Msg 21531, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSmerge_altertable, Line 367
The data definition language (DDL) command cannot be executed at the Subscriber. DDL commands can only be executed at the Publisher. In a republishing hierarchy, DDL commands can only be executed at the root Publisher, not at any of the republishing Subscribers.
Msg 21530, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSmerge_ddldispatcher, Line 191
The schema change failed during execution of an internal replication procedure. For corrective action, see the other error messages that accompany this error message.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

The statement which threw the problem is:

```
PRINT N'Altering dbo.YourTableHere...';
GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YourTableHere]
         ADD [a_new_timestamp] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Is there anything I can configure to make my script run correctly without these warnings?

The computer I am running this script is acting as subscriber and it has a Replication that should be deleted?

Comment: Presumably, yesterday when it worked,  you weren't executing the exact same script on the exact same server (since you wouldn't want to add the same column twice). What's changed since then?

Comment: the script is the same and there is nothing to do with adding an new column since the warning is telling about `Procedure sp_MSmerge_ddldispatcher`

Comment: But the script has to be different because otherwise you wouldn't need to add that column because you would have added it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

We found traces of a replication that had been activated in the past in a specific table.

Replication was not fully removed from this table.

We also notice that the script works in different database name (a database with the same structure).

Here is the history:

- We restored database from `DATABASE_A` (with traces of replacation) to `DATABASE_B`
- We run the stript on `DATABASE_B` and it works
- We run the script on `DATABASE_A` and **it fails**

Our DBA found traces of replication in `DATABASE_A` and in order to clean up the replication traces, he had run:

```
sp_removedbreplication 'DATABASE_A'
```

I am not sure if there is something configured on system tables in SQL Server that are related to the name `DATABASE_A`. We are going to investigate this issue deeper to find dependencies or what is causing the error.

Comment: The stored procedure 'sp_removedbreplication' just saved me a ton of work, thanks! I had the same problem time and time again while using the SQL Management Studio UI to remove replication. Not sure why the GUI allows you to remove replication when it clearly leaves literally hundreds of thousands of DB triggers, system 'MSMerge_XXXX' tables and various other meta-data preventing further DLL operations.